# How Do I Can Send And Receive Data From Web Server Using C++ Language (MFC)

Tags: php, c++, web, server

Do you have any idea for send and receive data with POST/GET method from web Server using C++ language?

I have one Application A (using C++), Web Server B

Diagram:

```
A --> Send Data --> B --> Check Validate information --> return values --> A
```

I want to send information with two CString parameter to Web Server (PHP), and on this server will be check validate some rules on this information. And then send back to application A.

May someone give me solution or example for send and receive data in Application A, which API i can used?

Answer (score 0):

Investigate the well-regarded Microsoft "Casablanca" CppRest library - you can use it to query and process a REST interface. It would be simple from PHP to return the data you need in JSON format, which your application would consume.

See https://casablanca.codeplex.com/ - there are examples included.